# cannot find -lX11 on windows MSYS

Tags: makefile, x11, msys

I'm trying to compile a program that uses some X11 plotting window files.
I downloaded the files from `https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6/` and extracted them to a folder that is known.
As part of this process, I have two Makefile files (A and B).
Makefile B produces the library `libPlt_gfortran.a` without any errors.
Makefile A is supposed to compile some FORTRAN code and create an .exe file.
In Makefile A, I have the following lines that refer to some X11 library.

```
PLTOBJ = ../plotlib/libPlt_gfortran.a
PLTLIB =  -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

However, despite setting `PLTLIB` to the folder containing the extracted X11R6 files, I keep getting the following error when I try to `make` my program.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lX11
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I keep seeing people with very similar issues for this, as well as numerous fixes, however none of them are for windows users. Using linux/ubuntu is not an option at the moment as computers are all windows based and students cannot install any other operating system...

Current path of /usr/ folder on the Windows PC[/usr/ path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRnhA.png)

Comment: Have you performed a sanity check and verified `libX11.{so,a}` exists in `/usr/X11R6/lib`?

Comment: Yes, the `libX11.so/a ` files weren't present in the X11R6 files, so I downloaded them from here (this was the fix for linux users) `https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libx11-dev/download` and manually pasted the 2 files into `/usr/X11R6/lib` , however, the error still persisted. 
I checked if my /usr/ folder is correct. (MSYS usr folder is defaulted to `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0`, so I extracted the files into that folder.

Comment: I don't think debian binaries will work for Windows.

Comment: Oh I see.., would you know where I could get the appropriate files for windows?

Comment: Cygwin might have them, but you'd have to install Cygwin for that. You may have to build them manually

Comment: You might consider [XMing](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) for instance, unless you have a lot of time.

Comment: https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/cygwin-x-ug.html

Comment: Would I have to actually use Cygwin? Couldn't I just use the X11R6 source files from the Cygwin install folder to compile my program by changing `PLTLIB =  /C/cygwin/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11` ?